# "Shutdown tomcat server" etcpp. message to all currently logged in users

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, backend

I would like to inform all logged in users that the server will shutdown. This special interest would be nice in an ajaxfy application (RIA). 
What are the possible solutions? What are the best practice solutions?

There were two possible end-scenarios:

1. Send a text $x to the server ergo to all users. ("The server will not be available for some minutes.")
2. Send a key $y to the server which will used to generate a (custom) text to all users. ("SERVER_SHUTDOWN")

Environment: Tomcat (6/7), Spring 3+
Messaging to users: with polling or pseudo-pushing via an async servlet.

***Ideas***

**1. Context.destroy(): Implementing a custom ContextListener's destroy**

I don't think it is a good solution to block within a "destroy()" -- blocking, because we should wait about 5-10 seconds to make sure that all logged in users receive a message.

**2. JMX Beans**

This would mean, that any server service operation (start, stop) have to invoke a special program which sends the message.

**3. Any other messaging queues like AMQP or ActiveMQ**

Like 2.

Comment: From an end user perspective I cannot see any advantage as the user can't do anything to cancel the server shutdown. If you have a webserver upfront, I'd simply show a static page that the server was shutdown, next time the user tries to perform an action...

Answer (score 1):

Unless the server shuts down regularly and the shutdown has a significant impact on users (for e.g. they will lose any unsubmitted work - think halfway through editing a big post on a page) then notifying of server shutdown won't really be of much benefit.

There are a couple of things you *could* do.

First, if the server is going to be shutdown due to planned maintenance then you could include a message on web pages like;

> Server will be unavailable Monday 22nd Aug 9pm - 6am for planned
>   maintenance. Contact knalli@example.com for more information.

Second, before shutting down the server, redirect requests to a static holding page (just change your web server config). This holding page should have information on why the server is down and when it will be available again.

With both options, its also important to **plan** server downtime. It's normal to have maintenance windows outside of normal working hours. Alternatively, if you have more than one server you can cluster them. This allows you to take individual servers out of the cluster to perform maintenance *without having any server downtime at all*.

Comment: Well, your answer isn't bad, but...

But your last two paragraphs do not handle the speciality of a RIA. What about users which are currently logged in? My idea was a kind of notification message "hey, remember: we are going offline for some minutes".

Comment: I will agree it would be preferable having no server downtime at all.